# Translations and Symfony2 in database

Tags: symfony, translation

File based translations don't work for me because clients need to change the texts.

So I am thinking about implementing [this interface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/LoaderInterface.html) to fetch data from the database and cache the results in an APC cache.
Is this a good solution?

Comment: Note that Symfony caches the translations to a file regardless of the source of the translations. Symfony does this at the first run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

[Use a database as a translation provider in Symfony 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160619063201/http://blog.elendev.com:80/development/php/symfony/use-a-database-as-translation-provider-in-symfony-2/)

> ### Introduction
>
> This article explain how to use a database as translation storage in Symfony 2. Using a database to provide translations is quite easy to do in Symfony 2, but unfortunately it’s actually not explained in Symfony 2 website.
>
> ### Creating language entities
>
> At first, we have to create database entities for language management. In my case, I’ve created three entities : the Language entity contain every available languages (like *french, english, german*).
>
> The second entity is named *LanguageToken*. It represent every available language tokens. The *token* entity represent the *source* tag of the xliff files. Every translatable text available is a token. For example, I use *home_page* as a token and it’s translated as *Page principale* in french and as *Home page* in english.
>
> The last entity is the *LanguageTranslation* entity : it contain the translation of a token in a specific language. In the example below, the *Page principale* is a *LanguageTranslation* entity for the language *french* and the token *home_page*.
>
> It’s quite inefficient, but the translations are cached in a file by Symfony 2, finally it’s used only one time at Symfony 2 first execution (except if you delete Symfony 2’s cache files).
>
> The code of the *Language* entity is visible here :
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourApp\YourBundle\Repository\LanguageRepository")
>  */
> class Language {
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id 
>      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue
>      */
>     private $id;
>
>     /** @ORM\column(type="string", length=200) */
>     private $locale;
>
>
>     /** @ORM\column(type="string", length=200) */
>     private $name;
>
>
>     public function getId() {
>         return $this->id;
>     }
>
>     public function setId($id) {
>         $this->id = $id;
>     }
>
>     public function getLocale() {
>         return $this->locale;
>     }
>
>     public function setLocale($locale) {
>         $this->locale = $locale;
>     }
>     public function getName() {
>         return $this->name;
>     }
>
>     public function setName($name) {
>         $this->name = $name;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The code of the *LanguageToken* entity is visible here :
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourApp\YourBundle\Repository\LanguageTokenRepository")
>  */
> class LanguageToken {
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue
>      */
>     private $id;
>
>     /** @ORM\column(type="string", length=200, unique=true) */
>     private $token;
>
>
>     public function getId() {
>         return $this->id;
>     }
>
>     public function setId($id) {
>         $this->id = $id;
>     }
>
>     public function getToken() {
>         return $this->token;
>     }
>
>     public function setToken($token) {
>         $this->token = $token;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And the *LanguageTranslation* entity’s code is visible here :
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourApp\YourBundle\Repository\LanguageTranslationRepository")
>  */
> class LanguageTranslation {
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue
>      */
>     private $id;
>
>     /** @ORM\column(type="string", length=200) */
>     private $catalogue;
>
>
>     /** @ORM\column(type="text") */
>     private $translation;
>
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourApp\YourBundle\Entity\Language", fetch="EAGER")
>      */
>     private $language;
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourApp\YourBundle\Entity\LanguageToken", fetch="EAGER")
>      */
>     private $languageToken;
>
>
>     public function getId() {
>         return $this->id;
>     }
>
>     public function setId($id) {
>         $this->id = $id;
>     }
>
>     public function getCatalogue() {
>         return $this->catalogue;
>     }
>
>     public function setCatalogue($catalogue) {
>         $this->catalogue = $catalogue;
>     }
>
>     public function getTranslation() {
>         return $this->translation;
>     }
>
>     public function setTranslation($translation) {
>         $this->translation = $translation;
>     }
>
>     public function getLanguage() {
>         return $this->language;
>     }
>
>     public function setLanguage($language) {
>         $this->language = $language;
>     }
>
>     public function getLanguageToken() {
>         return $this->languageToken;
>     }
>
>     public function setLanguageToken($languageToken) {
>         $this->languageToken = $languageToken;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ### Implementing a LoaderInterface
>
> The second step is to create a class implementing the *Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface*. The corresponding class is shown here :
>
> ```php
> class DBLoader implements LoaderInterface{
>     private $transaltionRepository;
>     private $languageRepository;
>
>     /**
>      * @param EntityManager $entityManager
>      */
>     public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
>         $this->transaltionRepository = $entityManager->getRepository("AppCommonBundle:LanguageTranslation");
>         $this->languageRepository = $entityManager->getRepository("AppCommonBundle:Language");
>     }
>
>     function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages'){
>         //Load on the db for the specified local
>         $language = $this->languageRepository->getLanguage($locale);
>
>         $translations = $this->transaltionRepository->getTranslations($language, $domain);
>
>         $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale);
>
>         /**@var $translation Frtrains\CommonbBundle\Entity\LanguageTranslation */
>         foreach($translations as $translation){
>             $catalogue->set($translation->getLanguageToken()->getToken(), $translation->getTranslation(), $domain);
>         }
>
>         return $catalogue;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The *DBLoader* class need to have every translations from the *LanguageTranslationRepository* (the *translationRepository* member). The *getTranslations($language, $domain)* method of the *translationRepository* object is visible here :
>
> ```php
> class LanguageTranslationRepository extends EntityRepository {
>
>     /**
>      * Return all translations for specified token
>      * @param type $token
>      * @param type $domain 
>      */
>     public function getTranslations($language, $catalogue = "messages"){
>         $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT t FROM AppCommonBundle:LanguageTranslation t WHERE t.language = :language AND t.catalogue = :catalogue");
>         $query->setParameter("language", $language);
>         $query->setParameter("catalogue", $catalogue);
>
>         return $query->getResult();
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The *DBLoader* class will be created by Symfony as a service, receiving an *EntityManager* as constructor argument. All arguments of the *load* method let you customize the way the translation loader interface work.
>
> ### Create a Symfony service with DBLoader
>
> The third step is to create a service using the previously created class. The code to add to the config.yml file is here :
>
> ```
> services:
>     translation.loader.db:
>         class: MyApp\CommonBundle\Services\DBLoader
>         arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
>         tags:
>             - { name: translation.loader, alias: db}
> ```
>
> The *transation.loader* tag indicate to Symfony to use this translation loader for the *db* alias.
>
> ### Create fake translation files
>
> The last step is to create an *app/Resources/translations/messages.xx.db* file for every translation (with xx = en, fr, de, …).
>
> I didn’t found the way to notify Symfony to use *DBLoader* as default translation loader. The only quick hack I’ve found is to create a *app/Resources/translations/messages.en.db* file. The *db* extension correspond to the *db* alias used in the service declaration. A corresponding file is created for every language available on the website, like *messages.fr.db* for french or *messages.de.db* for german.
>
> When Symfony find the *messages.xx.db* file he load the *translation.loader.db* to manage this unknown extension and then the *DBLoader* use database content to provide translation.
>
> I’ve also didn’t found the way to clean properly the translations cache on database modification (the cache have to be cleaned to force Symfony to recreate it). The code I actually use is visible here :
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * Remove language in every cache directories
>  */
> private function clearLanguageCache(){
>     $cacheDir = __DIR__ . "/../../../../app/cache";
>
>     $finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
>
>     //TODO quick hack...
>     $finder->in(array($cacheDir . "/dev/translations", $cacheDir . "/prod/translations"))->files();
>
>     foreach($finder as $file){
>         unlink($file->getRealpath());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This solution isn’t the pretiest one (I will update this post if I find better solution) but it’s working ^^
>
> Be Sociable, Share!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Translatable behavior extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) for Doctrine 2. [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) integrates it with Symfony.

Comment: i have looked it but this is for entities not for random text!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look into this Loader + Resource using PDO connection: https://gist.github.com/3315472

You then only need to make it cache aware, like adding a memcache, apc, .. in between.
If so, you can then disable the filecaching of the Translator itself.