# How to use a Symfony Translator in my Twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've been working on translating my application, I pull the translations from my database and add them to a catalogue. Everything works within Symfony, if I echo a translation with `$translator->trans('TEST_TRANSLATION')` for example it echoes the correct value, so I assume that my translations are correct.

Now I use Twig as my template engine, which supports translations with the {% trans %} tags. Sadly the translations from the translator variable don't work within Twig and after Googling for quite a while I can't seem to find a working solution.
  I've read about doing something with adding extensions using `$twig->addExtension()`, but I can't get that to work.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or maybe even provide a clearer explanation on how to achieve using the translator with the {% trans %} tags.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's the code from the Controller I use to create a translator:

```
$this->translator = new Translator('en');
$this->translator->addLoader('array', new ArrayLoader());
$this->translator->addResource('array', $translations, 'en');

echo $this->translator->trans('TEST_TRANSLATION');
```

The $translations variable contains an array with the translations, when using echo it shows the given translation correctly. How can I get this translator to work in Twig when using `<p>{% trans %}TEST_TRANSLATION{% endtrans %}</p>`?

**Edit 2**: I've been trying all kinds of stuff in the last 1,5 hours, but nothing works. I have found out however that giving the translator to the array for the render function of the Twig template enables me to acces its variables, I do this as follows:

```
return $this->render('test/transTest.html.twig', array('translator'=>$this->translator));
```

If I use the above I can access the translation variables within Twig by doing:

```
<p>{{ translator.trans('TEST_TRANSLATION') }}</p>
```

Using`<p>{{ translator.locale }}</p>` also gives me the right locale information.

I am pretty sure now that nothing is wrong with translations, but the site I'm working on uses {% trans %} for translations within Twig and I still have no idea how to get my Translator translations to work with those. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work how? Make sure you have correct locale set `{{ app.request.locale }}`

Comment: with the trans filter? {{'TEST_TRANSLATION'|trans}}

Comment: I've tried both the {% trans %} tags and {{'TEST_TRANSLATION'|trans}}, the locale is also correct. It seems like Twig cannot access the translator class I create in the Controller. I'm searching for a way to use the translator I create in the Controller within Twig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation are not working in twig with the tag `{% trans %}` or with the filter `|trans` because you are not using the default translator service of Symfony but one you just instantiate.

You can load the translation from the database in a custom loader service declared in the container with the tag [`translation.loader`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-translation-loader) so that translator service will be aware of them.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220206/translations-and-symfony2-in-database) and the (quite old) advise [tutorial](http://blog.elendev.com/development/php/symfony/use-a-database-as-translation-provider-in-symfony-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The tutorial you've linked is the exact one I've been using to create what I have now. The only difference between between my code and the code from the tutorial is that I use the class 'AppBundle\Utils\DBLoader' and he uses the class 'MyApp\CommonBundle\Services\DBLoader'. I've tried clearing my cache, but that doesn't seem to help. I don't have to instantiate or call that service at all in my controller? I'm not too experienced with Symfony, so I have no idea how the load() function would be called.

Comment: Nevermind, already fixed it. It took me 2 hours, but I finally realised that my domains have different names and not just 'messages', I created some new translation files and everything works. Thanks for the help!